# How to reconnect socket with no delay after cable unplugged

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets, network-programming

I have a WPF client application that connects to multiple servers which are embedded devices.  Each connection is held open for hours, or possibly days.  Periodically a server will be unplugged from the network and then plugged back into the network.  If the user gracefully disconnects the socket before unplugging, everything works well.  However, if the user unplugs without disconnecting from the socket first then it will take several attempts to reconnect the socket.  Each connection attempt takes about 60 seconds.  It is annoying to have to wait a minute or more to re-establish communication.

When the cable is unplugged, the socket enters a FIN_WAIT_1 state (observed via NETSTAT).  I'd like to forcibly shutdown the socket and make it faster to reconnect when this happens.  How can I close the socket to avoid troublesome delays when reconnecting?

The command processing loop:

```
    Dim _socket As TcpClient

    Private Sub ProcessCommands()
    Dim command As Byte()
    Dim response As New StringBuilder
    Dim nextByte As Integer
    Dim receiveResponse As Boolean

    Using socketStream As NetworkStream = _socket.GetStream()
        While (True)
            Try
                socketStream.WriteTimeout = SOCKET_TIMEOUT
                socketStream.ReadTimeout = SOCKET_TIMEOUT

                'grab the next message and send it over the network
                command = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_commands.Take(_cancelPumpMessages.Token) + vbCr)
                socketStream.Write(command, 0, command.Length)
                socketStream.Flush()
                receiveResponse = True

                'await the response
                While (receiveResponse)
                    nextByte = socketStream.ReadByte()
                    If nextByte < 0 Then Exit While 'socket it closed
                    If nextByte = DELIMITER Then
                        'end of the message, let the listeners know
                        RaiseEvent ResponseReceived(Me, response.ToString)
                        response.Clear()
                        receiveResponse = False
                    Else
                        response.Append(Chr(nextByte))
                    End If
                End While
            Catch ex As ArgumentNullException
                Exit While
            Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
                Exit While
            Catch ex As SocketException
                Exit While
            Catch ex As IOException
                Exit While
            Catch ex As ObjectDisposedException
                Exit While
            Catch ex As OperationCanceledException
                Exit While
            End Try
        End While
    End Using
    Disconnect()
End Sub
```

Disconnect method:

```
    Public Sub Disconnect() Implements IConnection.Disconnect
    If _socket IsNot Nothing Then
        StopPolling()
        Try
            If _cancelPumpMessages IsNot Nothing Then _cancelPumpMessages.Cancel()
        Catch ex As ObjectDisposedException
            'pass
        End Try
        _socket.Close()
        _socket.Dispose()
        _socket = Nothing
    End If
    Status = ConnectionState.Disconnected
End Sub
```

Comment: Side-note: I think this approach might mask the issue of "lost" messages for some degree, but will not solve it. I doubt if there's a way to avoid implementing an `ACK` review for your application protocol layer. As you probably know, `FIN_WAIT` is set whenever a packet is sent (it has nothing to do with the cable being unplugged) and the timeout settings for the TCP/IP connection are connection wide (not just when an actual error occurs). If you minimize the timeout, you might experience disconnections during network delays.

Comment: Yes, my understanding is that the connection is left in FIN_WAIT_X without a response from the remote machine, which doesn't mean an unplugged cable necessarily, but practically speaking in this scenario it does since normal network delays are a in a couple hundred milliseconds.

Comment: Are the delays ~200ms or the `ping`? Is there a chance for lost packets? Are you on an open network or a closed one? ... once you review the risks, maybe review the [`setsockopt` man](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt)  as well as the [`socket`(7) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/7/socket)) and the [protocol information](https://linux.die.net/man/7/ip) for more ideas.

Comment: Code has been in production for 9 years in hundreds of closed networks.  The timeouts on read/write (set to 7000ms) correctly exit the command loop and call the Disconnect() method,  but we have issues reconnecting after a timeout.  If the Disconnect() method is called by an event handler on button-press before unplugging the cable then no issues.  I'll check out the thread.

Comment: Cool... by the way, my bad... I meant to write that `FIN_WAIT` is sent for any disconnection not any packet. As for the networks, considering they are closed networks, I think you should be fine setting a lower value. I'm sorry if my comments seemed unnecessary. I just wanted to give a "heads up" in case you weren't aware (which you obviously are).

Comment: P.S. I wonder if there's anything preventing the code from opening a new connection before the `Disconnect` operation is complete... Maybe the timeout question could be circumvented rather than solved.

Comment: You can create new socket object, but the connection won't succeed for a couple of tries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145249/discussion-between-gbc-and-myst).